# Proving that the torsion submodule is actually a submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am studying algebra from Thomas Hungerford and I was unable to give proof of following result left for reader.

> Question : Let A be a left module over an integral domain R and for each $a\in A$ let $O_{a}= \{ r\in R \mid ra=0\} $ . Then prove that $A_{t} =\{ a\in A\mid  O_{a} \neq 0\}$ is a submodule of A.

Attempt: Clearly $A_{t} $ is a subset of A.

Let $a, b$ $\in O_{a} $ . So, there exists $r_{1}$  st $r_{1} a=0$ and $r_{1}\neq 0$ and there exists $r_{2}$ st $r_{2} b=0$ and $r_{2}\neq 0$.

Then what $x$ should I choose such that $x\neq 0$ and $x(a-b)=0$ . I tried by taking $r_{1} r_{2} $ but it will not do.

Can anyone please tell how should I proceed?

Comment: Why $r_1 r_2$ does not work?

Comment: Perhaps they worry that $r_1r_2=0$ though of course that’s why the ring is assumed to be a domain.

Comment: @TokenToucan got it thanks!!